# Capture standard output of a python program as it happens

Tags: c#, python, redirectstandardoutput

I'm trying to write a C# program that captures the standard output in a python program. My problem is that all of the output comes after the program has executed rather than when it actually happens. As an example, for this python program:

```
print "Hello"
time.sleep(2)
print "Hello"
```

I would expect to get "Hello", a two second gap, and then another "Hello". The actual result is a two second gap and then "Hello", "Hello".

If I run the above python script from the command line, I get the desired behaviour. If the command prompt can do this, then I should be able to mimic that functionality without having to flush the buffer repeatedly.

I'm using this to run the process from C#:

```
_proc = new Process
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                                {
                                    FileName = "C:\\Python27\\python.exe",
                                    Arguments = pyScript,
                                    RedirectStandardError = true,
                                    UseShellExecute = false,
                                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                                    CreateNoWindow = true
                                }
            };
_proc.OutputDataReceived += ProcOnOutputDataReceived;
_proc.Start(); 
_proc.BeginOutputReadLine();
```

I can run this C# code (and changing the ProcessStartInfo properties above to run C# executable) and it behaves correctly:

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello");
Thread.Sleep(2000);
Console.WriteLine("Hello");
```

With this code I get "Hello", a two second gap, and then another "Hello".

Any idea why? How can I get the python interpreter to send the standard output as it happens?

Comment: Sounds like a buffering problem. Try flushing `sys.stdout` after the print.

Comment: In Windows, the normal behavior is that standard output just piles up until the child process exits. But this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10940793/424129 -- which points here -- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.beginoutputreadline.aspx -- but the guy whose answer it is deserves the credit!

Comment: I should have done more research. The question was answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2380649/redirect-python-standard-input-output-to-c-sharp-forms-application?rq=1

Comment: I wasn't even thinking about the interpreter option. I upvoted Chris Vig on the other thread. I would also like to point out that running in interpreter mode also means the calling program can send Python statements to its stdin...

Answer (score 7):

I know this is old but running `python` with `-u` option (unbuffered) seems to be what you were after.

Unbuffered will not wait before flushing output.
Running python without this option, output is flushed when:

- The buffer is full
- You call `sys.stdout.flush()`
- The process ends

Answer (score 2):

You need to flush the output buffer.

```
import sys
sys.stdout.flush()
```

See this question: [How to flush output of Python print?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-to-flush-output-of-python-print)

Comment: thanks but I need to be able to do this without updating each script to flush after a print. The command prompt can do this so I presume it is possible

Answer (score 0):

Good 
(Capture standard output of a python program as it happens)
Em console is NEED:
import sys
sys.stdout.flush()